# Page not reloading on navigate("/") (svelte-routing)

Tags: javascript, url, routes, svelte

I am working on a website and there for using Svelte and the svelte-routing library .
The svelte-routing library has a method called navigate(path).
I use this function on a click of a button and it works perfectly. But in my routeHandling.js file its not working as expected.
I can see that it sets the url in the browser but its staying on the same page, so I have to press F5 (reload the page) to load the page.

```
import {navigate} from "svelte-routing";
import * as axios from "axios";

export function checkLoggedIn() {
    console.log("checkLoggedIn is now getting executed");
    if (window.location.pathname !== "/" && window.location.pathname !== "/registration") {
        axios.default.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/user', {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `${localStorage.getItem("token")}`
            }
        }).catch(response => {
            navigate("/");
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the same problem. After `navigate(routeUri)` the route in URL box in the browser changes, but the new route does not render.
Home.svelte:
```typescript
<script lang="ts">
import {navigate} from 'svelte-routing' ;
$: navigate( '/contest/list');

<div>
</div>
```
The same problem happens with login: if the component ContestList detects that user is not logged in, in `fetch( jsonAPIUrl ).then( response => { ... if(not_logged_in) navigate( '/login')` - also does not render login page.  Same after successful login... All pages render fine if clicked from `<Link to="...">`

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the `navigate` method inside a svelte component. Try creating a method that calls the `checkLogggedIn()` method from your svelte component and does `navigate()` on successful return.

```
import checkLoggedIn from "./router";
import {navigate} from "svelte-routing";

const checkUser = async () => {
  let res = await checkLoggedIn();
  if (res.status === 200) {
    navigate('/')
  } else {
    navigate('/login')
  }
}
```

something like this should work. you'll want to wait for the response before navigating so I made it an async function

Another thing you will want to check is if you're using the `-s or -single` flag when you start svelte. Check your NPM scripts.

Just in case you're new to svelte-routing:
you need to add a `Router` to your App, and create paths with the componenets to be rendered on them. like this

```
<Router>

<Route path="home">
  <Home />
</Route>

<Route path="about">
  <About />
<Route />

</Router>
```

where the `<Home />` and `<About />` are components you would like to render on those routes.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `location.replace("/")`to reload and get all the components.
But you are removing the history for the first page so you can't go back.

```
const checkUser = async () => {
  let res = await checkLoggedIn();
  if (res.status === 200) {
      location.replace("/");
  } else {
    navigate('/login')
  }
}
```

or you could do a `location.reload();` after navigate to keep the history

```
if (res.status === 200) {
  navigate('/')          
  location.reload();
} else {
    navigate('/login')
  }
}
```